# Application Insights filter Data Out request

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a chart in application insights and I want to see what request resulted in this massive data out of 64MB during a time period. It drained our application memory. Does anyone know how to filter the Application Insights data down to see what this was?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Pd9.png]

Comment: can you please let me know where you get the chart? detailed steps is very helpful.

Comment: Sure, if you browse to your Windows Azure Web App, you can see the Data In and Out panel graphs. Drilling in we saw a point where an excess amount of data was going out. We believe this was the web call that resulted in draining our system resources. It would be good to understand what that specific request was.

Answer (score 1):

For start you can run the following query in Analytics in Application Insights. Since you have the time (UTC) by running this query you can filter the requests.

```
requests
| extend itemType = iif(itemType == 'request',itemType,"")
| where (itemType == 'request' and (timestamp >= datetime(2019-02-26T07:21:00.000Z) and timestamp <= datetime(2019-02-26T07:22:00.000Z)))
```